# How to sum the Values of volume after re sampling Datafame in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to resample OHLC data from 1 hour to 4 hour using the below code. It all works except for the volume column is concatonating the values of each 1 hour interval instead of adding the values together to produce 1 4H interval. 
Any suggestions much appreciated?

```
data = {'Date':['2019-10-27 16:00:00', '2019-10-27 17:00:00', '2019-10-27 18:00:00', '2019-10-27 19:00:00', '2019-10-27 20:00:00', '2019-10-27 21:00:00', '2019-10-27 22:00:00', '2019-10-27 23:00:00'],
        'Open':[10, 15, 11, 16, 11, 10, 9, 8],
        'High':[18, 17, 12, 17, 17, 19, 20, 18],
        'Low':[9, 15, 10, 14, 10, 10, 8, 8],
        'Close':[18, 17, 11, 17, 16, 19, 18, 17]
        'Volume':[108, 107, 102, 107, 107, 188, 176]
        }

OHLC_DF = pd.DataFrame(data) 

OHLC_DF_dict = {                                                                                                             
'Open':'first',                                                                                                    
'High':'max',                                                                                                       
'Low':'min',                                                                                                        
'Close': 'last',                                                                                                    
'Volume': 'sum'
}

OHLC_DF = OHLC_DF.resample('4H', how=OHLC_DF_dict, closed='left', label='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [aggreagate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html)

```
OHLC_DF.resample('4H', closed='left', label='left').aggregate(OHLC_DF_dict)
```